# Can "less" means "else"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm not an English native speaker, and I have this memory in my head that less could be used like else, like this:

> He doesn't want to overdo it, less it ends up backfiring.

I looked up online, and I found nothing, most likely am wrong but can't help ask.
please help me clarify this issue, thank you.

Comment: You are probably thinking of "lest".

Comment: Yep, that must be it, thank you.

Comment: You are on the wrong site. Check out [SE English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) which may be suitable.

Comment: Do you know of something like prior notice as "a heed (on, in...) ".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word you are thinking of is "*lest*", not "*less*".

Google's dictionary says:

> - with the intention of preventing (something undesirable); to avoid the risk of.
>     "he spent whole days in his room, headphones on lest he disturb anyone"
> - (after a clause indicating fear) because of the possibility of something
>     undesirable happening; in case.
>     "she sat up late worrying lest he be held up on the way home"
>
> Similar: in case, just in case, for fear that, in order to avoid, to avoid the risk of

Interestingly, in its original Old English form "lest" *did* include the word "less":

```
"thȳ lǣs the" (whereby less that)  →  "the læste"  →  "lest".
```

In Old English syntax your statement would have been something like: "*He doesn't want to overdo it, thereby less that it ends up backfiring*".